# unable to resolve class DataflowVariable on GPars/Groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gpars

I am a beginner in Groovy/GPars. I am trying to run the example code from the following documentation (http://gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/dataflow.html):

```
import static groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflow.task
final def x = new DataflowVariable()
final def y = new DataflowVariable()
final def z = new DataflowVariable()

task {
    z << x.val + y.val
}

task {
    x << 10
}

task {
    y << 5
}

println "Result: ${z.val}"
```

My build.gradle file has the following dependencies/configuration:

```
    plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy:4.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.codehaus.gpars', name: 'gpars', version: '1.0.0' //1.2.1
    implementation "org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}
```

But when I run my file, I obtain the error "unable to resolve class DataflowVariable".
I have tried to change the gpars version to 1.0.0 to correspond with the following documentation: http://gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/dataflow.html

I have no issues with other imports such as "groovyx.gpars.dataflow.stream.DataflowStream", so I don't understand why I have this error for DataflowVariable.

Comment: Have you tried importing it? e.g. `import groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowVariable` (picked that one from the docs, might no longer be true). If you are not using an IDE, start now -- java and therefor groovy notoriously omits imports in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cfrick's comment was right you were missing the `import groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowVariable`

```
import static groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflow.task
import groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowVariable

final def x = new DataflowVariable()
final def y = new DataflowVariable()
final def z = new DataflowVariable()

task {
    z << x.val + y.val
}

task {
    x << 10
}

task {
    y << 5
}

println "Result: ${z.val}"
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_4_0&codez=eJyNjs0KwjAQhO95iqUIUZRQD17EggfBuwfv2zatwZiUJK39oe9uoxS0IDqX3R2-GXZ_NBjPc6PLIqLa5CzRKb9gaVleoLF0BTedlpJHdLwrbqzQKqJrFrKQLoi4Fdo4sA6dSGCo0lVTv-IsRYeZ1Hd2GBeH9jpGfrBnNAJjyQnJhEIJKc-ghggUv8OUmS_eoOYfqP0OEf8kdAQGtbDbQc2qIbWExk_SfwC1B9bhxG28u_FmYYRyUkFw4raUbguzrvU1fUDIEx31AKuMf00)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code as an IDE. I have experimented with changing "import static groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflow.task", but none of these have worked.

Comment: Have you tried copy and pasting my example exactly? As you can see in the Groovy Web Console it works.

Comment: Yes, now it works! Initially, I only copied and pasted the second line since it seems to be the only difference in code; but now I copied and pasted everything and it works. I don't understand how that can be.

Comment: @mariestr if it solved your problem please accept the answer, even if it was a trivial thing in the end.